# Unable to swipe in Appium Inspector for iOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I'm currently using Appium inspector for an iOS app in Browserstack. Previously, I've been able to use the swipe function fine when searching for elements, but when i do this for iOS, it just registers as a click. I need to know why this is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

On my case, swiping and tapping work fine on

```
 iOS 13.4 
 Xcode 11.4 
 mac os 10.15.4
```

- however, it does not work on 11.0, 11.1 and 11.2 ios versions.